# How to remove data with firebase-admin?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

So, I'm using this firebase-admin library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin). I read the docs from Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data). But I can't find the section how to remove the data with firebase-admin.

I do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
router.get('/delete_category', function(req, res, next) {
  var key = req.query.item;
  let del_ref = admin.database().ref("product/" + key);
  del_ref.remove() 
});
```

Can you guys help me on how to delete the data from my firebase database with firebase-admin? Thanks in advance

**Notes:** I am using NodeJS with Express Framework and Handlebars

Answer (score 17):

Your code looks correct. The [`remove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#remove) method is what you want to use. You probably just need to add a completion listener to ensure that the `remove()` call was successful:

```
router.get('/delete_category', function(req, res, next) {
  var key = req.query.item;
  let del_ref = admin.database().ref("product/" + key);
  del_ref.remove()
    .then(function() {
      res.send({ status: 'ok' });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error deleting data:', error);
      res.send({ status: 'error', error: error });
    });
});
```

Comment: Still no luck mate, I get status 'ok' but my data still in the firebase db. How is that possible?

Comment: Ah, finally I know whats wrong here. I put the wrong references. Thanks for the response mate!

Comment: To remove using the admin SDK with realtime database, use delete()

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:** Finally I found the answer
I made mistake in the references here

```
let del_ref = admin.database().ref("product/" + key);
```

It should be read the category ref like this:

```
let del_ref = admin.database().ref("category/" + key);
```